# Best way to match list of words with a list of job descriptions python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my problem (I'm working on python) : 
I have a Dataframe with columns: `Index(['job_title', 'company', 'job_label', 'description'], dtype='object')`

And I have a list of words that contains 300 skills:

```
keywords = ["C++","Data Analytics","python","R", ............ "Django"]
```

I need to match those keywords with each of the jobs descriptions and obtain a new dataframe saying if is true or false that C++ is in job description[0]...job description[1], job description[2] and so on.

My new dataframe will be:

> columns : ['job_title', 'company', 'description', "C++", "Data Analytics",
>   ....... "Django"]

Where each column of keywords said true or false if it match(is found) or not on the job description.

There might be another ways to structure the dataframe (I'm listening suggestions).

Hope I'm clear with my question. I try regex but I can't make it iterate trough each row, I try with a loop using "fnmatch" library and I can't make it work. The best approach so far was:

```
df["microservice"]= df.description.str.contains("microservice") 

df["cloud-based architecture"] = df.description.str.contains("cloud-based architecture")

df["service oriented architecture"] = df.description.str.contains("service oriented architecture")
```

However, First I could not manage to make it loop trough each rows of description column, so i have to input 300 times the code with each word (it doesn't make sense). Second, trough this way, I have problems with few words such as "R" because it find the letter R in each description, so it will pull true in each of them.

Comment: so, just to be sure, you want to be able to say if some words (new columns) are une the column named description?

Comment: do you need to check for common misspellings, plurals, and stem words (i.e. is it an exact match or a fuzzy match)?

Comment: You should probably add "pandas" tag to this question. Or at least, that what it looks like considering you're talking about dataframes.

Comment: Yes Alexis, and I think it will be more efficient if I can check misspellings plurals and stem words Jgreenwell

Comment: The best way to do that would be NLTK though there are other implementations. I would suggest you start with the answers given here but if you want to learn more you can read the book [NLP with Python](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over list of keywords and extract each column from the description one:

```
for name in keywords:
    df[name] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: True if name in x else False)
```

**EDIT**:

That doesn't solve the problem with R. To do so you could add a space to make sure it's isolated so the code would be:

```
for name in keywords:
    df[name] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: True if ' '+str(name)+' ' in x else False)
```

But that's really ugly and not optimised. Regular expression should do the trick but I have to look back into it: found it! [ ]*+[str(name)]+[.?!] is better! (and more appropriate)

Comment: Thank you so much!! @alexis

Answer (score 1):

One way is to build a regex string to identify any keyword in your string... this example is case insensitive and will find any substring matches - not just whole words...

```
import pandas as pd
import re

keywords = ['python', 'C++', 'admin', 'Developer']
rx = '(?i)(?P<keywords>{})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(kw) for kw in keywords))
```

Then with a sample DF of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'job_description': ['C++ developer', 'traffic warden', 'Python developer', 'linux admin', 'cat herder']
})
```

You can find all keywords for the relevant column...

```
matches = df['job_description'].str.extractall(rx)
```

Which gives:

```
               keyword
  match           
0 0            C++
  1      developer
2 0         Python
  1      developer
3 0          admin
```

Then you want to get a list of "dummies" and take the max (so you always get a 1 where a word was found) using:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(matches).max(level=0)
```

Which gives:

```
   keyword_C++  keyword_Python  keyword_admin  keyword_developer
0            1               0              0                  1
2            0               1              0                  1
3            0               0              1                  0
```

You then left join that back to your original DF:

```
result = df.join(dummies, how='left')
```

And the result is:

```
    job_description  keyword_C++  keyword_Python  keyword_admin  keyword_developer
0     C++ developer          1.0             0.0            0.0                1.0
1    traffic warden          NaN             NaN            NaN                NaN
2  Python developer          0.0             1.0            0.0                1.0
3       linux admin          0.0             0.0            1.0                0.0
4        cat herder          NaN             NaN            NaN                NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

- skill = "C++", or any of the others
- frame = an instance of
  `Index(['job_title', 'company', 'job_label', 'description'],
  dtype='object')`
- jobs = a list/np.array of frames, which is probably your input

A naive implementation could look a bit like this:

```
for skill in keywords:
    for frame in jobs: 
        if skill in frame["description"]: # or more exact matching, but this is what's in the question
            # exists
```

But you need to put more work into what output structure you are going to use. Just having an output array of 300 columns most of which just contain a `False` isn't going to be a good plan. I've never worked with Panda's myself, but if it were normal numpy arrays (which panda's DataFrames are under the hood), I would add a column "skills" that can enumerate them.

Comment: This solution will be awfully slow for large dataframes. There are many better ways to leverage the "under-the-hood" optimized methods available with a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Feel free to add. I've done my work mostly with numpy and some cv2 myself, never with panda's. Looks like Alexis got a better answer to handle the dataframes themselves. My major point is that you shouldn't store the results in a dataframe. Perhaps in a set contained in one.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `.apply()` like so (@Jacco van Dorp made a solid suggestion of storing all of the found skills inside a single column, which I agree is likely the best approach to your problem):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Engineer','Firm','AERO1','Work with python and Django'],
                    ['IT','Dell','ITD4','Work with Django and R'],
                    ['Office Assistant','Dental','OAD3','Coordinate schedules'],
                    ['QA Engineer','Factory','QA2','Work with R and python'],
                    ['Mechanic','Autobody','AERO1','Love the movie Django']],
                    columns=['job_title','company','job_label','description'])
```

Which yields:

```
          job_title   company job_label                  description
0          Engineer      Firm     AERO1  Work with python and Django
1                IT      Dell      ITD4       Work with Django and R
2  Office Assistant    Dental      OAD3         Coordinate schedules
3       QA Engineer   Factory       QA2       Work with R and python
4          Mechanic  Autobody     AERO1        Love the movie Django
```

Then define your skill set and your list comprehension to pass to `.apply()`:

```
skills = ['python','R','Django']

df['skills'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in skills if i in x['description'].split()], axis=1)
```

Which yields this column:

```
             skills  
0  [python, Django]  
1       [R, Django]  
2                []  
3       [python, R]  
4          [Django]
```

If you are still interested in having individual columns for each skill, I can edit my answer to provide that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much @rahlf23